# Make executable bash script run with sudo privileges?

Tags: bash, scripts, executable

Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome de.

I made a simple bash script file that flags my next reboot to choose the windows grub entry. For quick rebooting into windows straight from Linux DE.

The problem is I have to use dconf to modify executable files to ask, so I can click run in terminal where it automatically asks for password. Otherwise, just executing the file does nothing, bc it's waiting for a password input.

Is there a way to run a bash script file like this with inherent sudo privileges so it doesn't need to ask for a password?

**EDIT** (even though it's directed at @waltinator, because comment formatting is atrocious):

So would

```
/bin/kill
```

be the location and name of my bash script file?  for example, my bash script file is named restart2windows and is located on my desktop:

```
/home/myusername/Desktop/restart2windows
```

so I would just need to add this line to /etc/sudoers (I'm still unclear on editing that file, using visudo, and whether I should edit sudoers.d as advised):

```
myusername     mymachinename = NOPASSWD: /home/myusername/Desktop/restart2windows
```

Would this be correct?

**EDIT 2**

I tried editing sudoers via visudo:

```
sudo visudo
```

and added the line I suggested above, below the commented line:

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

and then tried to run my bash script file from my desktop, and it did nothing. If I choose to run it in the terminal, the terminal is waiting for a password input.

Here is my bash script file contents, very simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo grub-reboot 2
sudo reboot now
```

Found [this question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179398/why-is-sudoers-nopasswd-option-applying-the-exception-to-root-instead-of-specifi) and it appears that I need to add sudo somewhere in there? I'm confused by that answer to that question because his line of code from the OP does not match the OP's.

**Edit 3:**

I submitted this same post in Ubuntuforums.org as well: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2434878

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `man sudoers` - it will let you grant passwordless access to a single command. Read `man visudo`, too.

From the `man` page:

```
  PASSWD and NOPASSWD

   By default, sudo requires that a user authenticate him or herself before running a
   command.  This behavior can be modified via the NOPASSWD tag.  Like a Runas_Spec, the
   NOPASSWD tag sets a default for the commands that follow it in the Cmnd_Spec_List.
   Conversely, the PASSWD tag can be used to reverse things.  For example:

   ray     rushmore = NOPASSWD: /bin/kill, /bin/ls, /usr/bin/lprm

   would allow the user ray to run /bin/kill, /bin/ls, and /usr/bin/lprm as root on the
   machine rushmore without authenticating himself.  If we only want ray to be able to run
   /bin/kill without a password the entry would be:

   ray     rushmore = NOPASSWD: /bin/kill, PASSWD: /bin/ls, /usr/bin/lprm

   Note, however, that the PASSWD tag has no effect on users who are in the group specified
   by the exempt_group option.
```

Also, I'll note that "making an existing `bash` script run as `root`" is the beginning of many very sad security tales.

Rather than making the script run as `root`, allow your user passwordless access to the ( full path of ) the 2 commands in your script.

Comment: please see my post edit regarding what you've suggested and what I've interpreted from reading those man pages.

Comment: "Rather than making the script run as root, allow your user passwordless access to the ( full path of ) the 2 commands in your script."  Not sure what you mean exactly, I tried changing up the sudoers edit to say: 

`myusername     mymachinename = NOPASSWD: /home/myusername/Desktop/restart2windows/'sudo grub-reboot 2', /home/myusername/Desktop/restart2windows/'sudo reboot now'`

But when I tried to run the script by double clicking and clicking run at the prompt, it did nothing. At the prompt if I choose "run in terminal" the terminal opens and still is asking for a password....

Comment: No. The path of `grub-reboot` command. Not the path to a script on your Desktop. To find the path of a command: `which *name of command*`, for example: `which grub-reboot`.    Will return:   `/usr/sbin/grub-reboot`. That is the PATH to apply in you *sudoers* file . The path to the command you intend to use in your script.

Comment: @da_kingpin that makes much more sense. I'll try that tomorrow night after work. I'm adding a link in the OP to this same post I submitted in Ubuntuforums.org. A guy there has suggested putting this file in root/bin/ and chmod 700 it. Actually, after reading your suggestion I don't think I'd need to move the executable to root/bin/

Comment: @da_kingpin I just realized that in the script, if I just used the location of the command, how would I designate which grub entry to reboot to? /usr/sbin/grub-reboot is just the command but doesn't indicate which grub entry to choose.

Comment: Found something. In the file `/boot/grub/grubenv` you can add a parameter `next_entry=*number of menu entry to boot`. Have your script assign a vaule to change the parameter to.  The vaule would be the menu entry location  in your grub boot menu.  No `grub-update` needed. https://askubuntu.com/questions/635205/link-to-restart-from-windows-to-ubuntu. Also check the grub docs  https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html